# Projecting 3D points onto 2D coordinate system of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, projection

This is a rather basic question though I could not find a post with the answer.

I have a set of points in 3D. Let us define one of them $s$ as an observation point. we calculate the 3D Euclidean distances and choose the furthest point from $s$, denoted $r$. I want to span a 2D plane where the normal is $\overrightarrow{n}=\frac{\overrightarrow{sr}}{\left\|\overrightarrow{sr}\right\|}$. $\overrightarrow{sr}$ denotes the vector from point s to point r. I want to project the remaining points onto that plane and get their 2D values with the origin of the new system at $r$.

From all other projection answers I could find, I will get a 3D coordinate after the projection. My final goal is to calculate the 2D convex hull on the projected plane. How do I make the transition here?

Comment: Is $\overrightarrow{sr}$ refering to the vector from point s to point r? In the sense of: $\overrightarrow{sr} = \overrightarrow{r}- \overrightarrow{s}$?

Comment: @Manumerous yes, it does.

Comment: your problem seems to have close links with the PCA, try searching the web for principle component analysis

Comment: @AdityaGarg The difference is that I do not search for the axis with the biggest variance.

Comment: I think the problem tags could be adapted for this one. The convex hull is actually not an essential part of the problem. But it is related to linear algebra and vector spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the projected 3D points into 2D coordinates you first need to define a 2D coordinate system which is contained in your plane. For this you need to define the base vectors $\overrightarrow{e_x}$ and $\overrightarrow{e_y}$ of your coordinate frame. I assume that you would want a right-handed orthonormal base.

First you need to define your base vector $\overrightarrow{e_x}$. For this you can choose any unit vector, which is contained in your plane (orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{n}$, length 1).
One possibility would be to define your basis first basis vector $\overrightarrow{e_x}$ via $\overrightarrow{r}$:

$$\overrightarrow{e_x} = \frac{\overrightarrow{r} \times \overrightarrow{n}}{||\overrightarrow{r} \times \overrightarrow{n}||_2}$$

Where $\times$ denotes the vector cross product. This methods works unless $\overrightarrow{r}$ and $\overrightarrow{s}$ are parallel.
Once you have found any possible basis vector $e_x$ you can derive the right hand basis vector $e_y$ by:

$$ \overrightarrow{e_y} = \frac{\overrightarrow{n} \times \overrightarrow{e_x}}{||\overrightarrow{n} \times \overrightarrow{e_x}||_2}$$

We now denote $p'$ as the projection of an arbitrary point p onto the defined plane in 3D coordinates. We can then define the 3d vector denoting the distance of point p' to the origin of the new coordinate system by:

$$\overrightarrow{rp'} = \overrightarrow{p'} - \overrightarrow{r}$$

To get the 2D coordinates of that point you simply project the 3D vector of $p'$ onto our derived 3D vectors for $e_x$ and $e_y$ using the scalar product:

$$ p'_{\ 2D} =  \begin{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{rp'} \cdot \overrightarrow{e_x} \\ \overrightarrow{rp'} \cdot \overrightarrow{e_y} \end{pmatrix} $$

Finally you could reformulate the above equation into matrix form as follows:

$$ p'_{\ 2D} =  K \ \overrightarrow{rp'} = \begin{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{e_x}^T \\ \overrightarrow{e_y}^T \end{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{rp'} = \begin{pmatrix} e_{x,1} & e_{x,2} & e_{x,3} \\ e_{y,1} & e_{y,2} & e_{y,3} \end{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{rp'} $$

Where K denotes the projection matrix which you can simply apply to any 3D point in the defined plane. With this the transition to a 2D coordinate for a projected point is complete.